# Making new arrays within foreach loop using the loop values

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have an array of e-mails. I'm basically trying to create new arrays from the values in this array. For example, if there is an array "test@test.com", I want to create an array $test@test.com (or something like this; I understand that the @ symbol may be invalid). My head is all mixed up I think since I've been using jQuery and I can't figure out how to do this. I am familiar with reg_ex so I don't have a problem using that if that's what would work best. I'd like to name the arrays this so I can then assign certain things to them later corresponding to the e-mail address. Is this possible? Let me know if I'm way off bases here. Here's the code I have so far that's not working:

```
$email_array = array_unique($email_array);

//MAKE E-MAIL ARRAYS

foreach($email_array as $key => $value){
    $value = array(); //I'm aware this doesn't work, but this is the idea
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a multi-dimensional array:

```
$new_email_array = array();

foreach ( $email_array as $email ) {
    $new_email_array[ $email ] = array();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're trying to do, you can pass the value into the loop by reference like so

```
foreach($email_array as $key => &$value){
    $value = array();
}
unset($value);
```

That will modify the values. Also, the `unset($value)` at the end is to release the reference to `$value`. If you leave this out and reuse `$value`, you will modify the last item in `$email_array`.